# Qual o correto: Scrollar ou Escrolar

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras

Qual a palavra correta, "*scrollar*" ou "*escrollar*"?

Scroll no sentido de descer uma página no navegador.

Procurando no google, achei utilizações para as duas, e nenhuma ele mostrou como errada.

Comment: eu usuaria rolar, "rolar a página"...

Comment: Realmente, se tratando de português fica melhor.

Comment: Descocar a página.

Comment: Rolar a página certamente é a melhor opção ao invés de "scrollar". Fica totalmente sem sentido tentar *'portuguesiar'* essa frase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Achei poucas referências para ambas as opções. Encontrei *scroll* no Dicionário infopédia da Língua Portuguesa com Acordo Ortográfico ([link](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/Scroll)) e citado abaixo, mas não o verbo *scrollar* or *escrollar*.

> barra horizontal ou vertical localizada na parte lateral ou inferior
> do ecrã, que permite o deslocamento com o rato na área ativa; barra de
> deslocamento

Nesse caso consideraria uma gíria ainda e sem ser mapeada por dicionários.

Dessa forma, acredito que a melhor palavra a ser utilizada seria **rolar**, conforme traduções listadas pelo Linguee ([link](http://www.linguee.com.br/ingles-portugues/traducao/scroll.html)):

> percorrer (algo) v
>
> I scrolled the website until the end.
>
> Eu percorri o site até o fim.

Answer (score 4):

Em Portugal, o uso corrente é dizer «**fazer scroll**».

Apesar de esse ser o uso mais idiomático, no [CiberDúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-traducao-de-scroll-down/13816) indicam (e muito bem!) que:

> A tradução correcta de «scroll down» seria, tal como usa na pergunta, «*rolar para baixo*», ou, até, «deslocar para baixo».

Consolidando isso com documentação técnica:

> O [glossário desenvolvido](http://www.inst-informatica.pt/ct113/ing.htm) pela Comissão Técnica Portuguesa de Normalização de Terminologia Informática (CT 113) apresenta as opções «rolamento» e «deslizamento» para "scrolling".